# Getting specific key and value from jquery object

Tags: php, jquery

I am getting keys and values from php associative array to jquery object:

```
$names = array("Peter"=>"35", "Ben"=>"37", "Joe"=>"43");
$js = json_encode($names);
echo 'var names= ' . $js . ";";
```

Now I know how to iterate through all of the names and get their key and value:

```
$.each(names, function(key, value){
   alert(key + value);
});
```

But I need only specific value. For example how can I get only "Ben" and "37" without iterating through all the names?

Comment: `console.log(names.Ben);` ?

Comment: But I don't know the key. I don't know that the name is Ben. I would like to get the key as well as the value

Comment: Try to add new Array() like:
 echo 'var names= new Array( ' . $js . ");";

Comment: @matip if you don't know the key then how do you know what you're trying to retrieve? do you know the value?

Comment: I would like to get second key and value. Is that possible?

Comment: @matip are you tried to assign new array ?

Comment: @matip you can't (reliably), since the order of properties in an object is not guaranteed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `Object.keys`

```
var index = 1; // the nth key you want to fetch, 1 will be second
key = Object.keys(names)[index];
value = names[key];

console.log(key + ' -> ' + value);
```

Will output

```
Ben -> 37
```